# Expect script - stop evaluating after match and move on

Tags: expect

I'm attempting to write a small bash script with some embedded Expect scripting to send our router some predefined changes in the case of a failover to an alternate site.
My expect script in its simplest form works.  I'm running into uses in adding some error checking.

I'm attempting to call the "get policy id x" command on a juniper ssg router and then match that the policy we will be enabling or disabling is the correct one, then proceed to check that the VIP definitions are in fact running on this router, all before we make the changes.

The expect part of this script goes as follows…

```
# start the ssh connection, end unless we get a shell prompt
spawn ssh netscreen@duluthfw
expect {
    timeout  { send_user "\n Failed to get login prompt\n"; exit 1 }
    eof { send_user "\nSSH failure for hostname\n"; exit 1 }
    "*-> $"
    }
#Lets make sure this is the right policy, else lets check again

send "get policy id 9\r"
expect {
    default { send_user "\n This policy does not match the policy we need to enable, please look and set the POLICYNUM variable to the correct policy to enable.\n"; exit 1 }
    "VIP"  
    expect "*-> $"
        }   
send "get vip \r"
expect { 
default { send_user "These are not the VIP IPs or ports that we need to disable,  please verify this is being run against the correct router or that the failover has not already been implemented."; exit 1 }
        "HTTP" 
        send "unset interface wireless0/1 vip 192.168.35.3 port 80 \r"
        expect "*->"
        send "unset interface wireless0/1 vip 192.168.35.3 port 143 \r"
        expect "*- $"
        }
    }
}
```

The initial part of the script runs and matches on the VIP portion, but then moves to the 'send "get vip" command, and continues to evaluate the initial "get policy id" check instead of the return from the get vip command.

How do I tell expect to stop evaluating and move on to the next portion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want your expect blocks to look like this:

```
send "get policy id 9\r"
expect {
    default {
        send_user "\n This policy does not match the policy we need to enable, please look and set the POLICYNUM variable to the correct policy to enable.\n"
        exit 1 
    }
    "VIP"  
}
expect "*-> $"

send "get vip \r"
expect { 
    default {
        send_user "These are not the VIP IPs or ports that we need to disable,  please verify this is being run against the correct router or that the failover has not already been implemented."
        exit 1
    }
    "HTTP" 
}
expect "*-> $"
send "unset interface wireless0/1 vip 192.168.35.3 port 80 \r"
expect "*-> $"
send "unset interface wireless0/1 vip 192.168.35.3 port 143 \r"
expect "*-> $"
```

Expect blocks contain `pattern {action}` pairs. If the action is missing *for the last pattern* then the expect block ends and control proceeds from the next command.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.  That was exactly it.  My code looks like this now and is working.

```
send "get policy id 9 \r"
expect {
    default {
    send_user "\n WRONG POLICY This policy does not match the policy we need to enable, please look and set the POLICYNUM variable to the correct policy to enable.\n"
    exit 1
    }
    "VIP(192.168.35.3)"
}

send "get policy id 9 \r"
expect {
    default {
    send_user "\n NOT ENABLED This policy does not match the policy we need to enable, please look and set the POLICYNUM variable to the correct policy to enable.\n"
    exit 1
    }
    "enabled"
}

expect "*-> $"
send "set policy id 9 disable \r"
expect "*-> $"
send "get vip \r"
expect {
    default {
     send_user "These are not the VIP IPs or ports that we need to disable, please verify this is being run against the correct router or that the failover has not already been implemented."
      exit 1
      }
 "IMAP"
 }

 expect "*-> $"
 send "unset interface wireless0/1 vip 192.168.35.3 port 80 \r"
 expect "*-> $"
 send "unset interface wireless0/1 vip 192.168.35.3 port 143 \r"
 expect "*-> $"
```